# Cloudera Manager - HDFS Under-Replicated Blocks

Tags: hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I use a fresh install of `CDH 5.5.2`. In `Cloudera Manager` I see, that `HDFS` has a critical health issue. I have 1 `NameNode` and 1 `DataNode` in cluster.

> Under-Replicated Blocks

[image: Under-Replicated Blocks]

> 578 under replicated blocks in the cluster. 580 total blocks in the
>   cluster. Percentage under replicated blocks: 99.66%. Critical
>   threshold: 40.00%

How should I fix this issue?

UPDATE: `Cloudera Manager(CDH 5.0.2) -> HDFS -> Configuration -> View and Edit -> Service-Wide -> Replication -> Replication Factor (dfs.replication) -> 1` isn't working in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

- The namenode may be running with outdated configuration.  If so, restart the namenode to make sure that it is running with the current configuration displayed in cloudera manager.
- Sometimes the cloudera agent needs to be restarted as well for it to generate configurations properly
- If that doesn't work, then run `hadoop fsck /|egrep -v '^\.+$'|grep -i replica`
- find out the files affected and verify that the replication factor is set to 1 since you have only one datanode

  - you can check replication factor for a file by running `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/file.txt` then look at the number in the 2nd column in the output

Note:
be sure to add the HDFS Gateway role to the server you want to run the `hadoop` commands from.

Also consider upgrading cloudera manager to 5.5.1 - your version is a very early version and they made a TON of changes since then.

Answer (score 2):

The new replication factor affects only new files. To change replication factor for existing files run in shell (on the node with hadoop entry point)

```
hadoop fs -setrep -w <replication factor> -R /
```

But, only "hdfs" can write to / ("hdfs" is the superuser, not "root"). So, may be you will have to use this command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -setrep -w <replication factor> -R /
```